# Inserting rectangle in order to surround certain area (few raster cells) using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I´ve done a suitability analysis and now I need to point to this certain area.

Is it possible to select and frame certain raster cells to enlighten those? 
Or can somebody explain how to insert a simple rectangle that cover an area somewhat precise?

Comment: Are you looking to add an enlarged area to your map with the chosen area? Or just to draw a graphic around the area?

Comment: An enlarged area would be perfect, but a simple graphic around the area will do too! Now i am struggling with an extent rectangle by inserting another data frame, but it´s not covering the whole area, because the area is not a perfect rectangle.

Comment: And [Raster To Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) won't work for you because?

Comment: It works, but is it possible to select a specific group of raster cells in the conversion? Beacuse i don´t want all the cells in that class coverted.

Comment: @GBG I think you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have completed a suitability analysis then you have some raster cells attributed as suitable and the other cells unsuitable (or more suitable and less suitable). Use reclassify to convert the desired suitable cells to a value of 1 and the unsuitable cells to a value of NoData.

Finally, you can the convert the reclassified values to a polygon to get your highlighted area or use the reclassified raster to mask out the area you don't want to highlight.  To mask, symbolize the 1 values with no color and the NoData values as white.  Put the layer on top of the stack.